# What is the lifetime of reference member default initializer in C++?

Tags: c++, default-value

Please consider this short code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A() "; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() "; }
};

struct B { const A &a = A(); };

int main()
{
    B x;
    std::cout << ". ";
    auto y = B();
    std::cout << ". ";
    auto z = B{};
    std::cout << ". ";
}
```

GCC prints here ( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a83bn54qT ):

```
A() ~A() . A() ~A() . A() . ~A()
```

meaning that the lifetime of `A`-object initializing reference in `x` and `y` is short, but in `z` the lifetime is prolonged till the end of the scope.

Could you please explain why it is so from C++ standard point of view?

Comment: It sounds like a compiler-specific behavior which can't be relied on. IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lifetime extension is not guaranteed since the code is ill-formed.

[[class.base.init]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#11):

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member from a default
> member initializer is ill-formed. [Example 8:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A() = default;        // OK
>   A(int v) : v(v) { }   // OK
>   const int& v = 42;    // OK
> };
> A a1;                   // error: ill-formed binding of temporary to reference
> A a2(1);                // OK, unfortunately
> ```
>
> — end example]

Comment: Do you mean the code example above is up to compiler, or it is an undefined behavior?

Comment: @Fedor I believe it's UB, compilers are free to do anything.

Comment: Gotta love the "*OK, unfortunately*" comment in the C++ spec :-)

Comment: What about z-case above, or in this simplified version: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/W9rxv78o9 GCC does not give any warning here. If the program is still ill-formed, then no-warnings is a compiler bug, right?

Comment: @Fedor Yes I think so, the compiler should issue a diagnostic here.